# What does the error stat_count() reference in a ggplot visualization?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

What does the error stat_count() reference in a ggplot visualization?

For example, I have the following dataframe.

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Next, I plot it using ggplot and geom_bar().

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  xlab("x") + 
  ylab("y") + 
  ggtitle("x and y")
```

I get the error:

> Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

What does the error `stat_count()` reference in a ggplot visualization, and how do I resolve it to make a successful bar plot?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`. So the `stat_count()`  function uses the y variable given in `aes()`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct geom to plot bars with specified `y` values is `geom_col()`:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  xlab("x") + 
  ylab("y") + 
  ggtitle("x and y")
```

[image]

The geom you used, `geom_bar()`, wants to calculate the height of the bars by calling `stat_count()`. And `stat_count()` doesn't take a `y` aesthetics because it calculates its own `y` value.

If we want to use `geom_bar()` but don't want it to do any counting, we have to tell it so explicitly by setting `stat="identity"` (this then calls `stat_identity()` instead of `stat_count()`):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  xlab("x") + 
  ylab("y") + 
  ggtitle("x and y")
```

However, this approach is now discouraged.